# Run unit tests while using --no-sound-null-safety

Tags: flutter, unit-testing

My app uses the MVP pattern as its main Architecture Pattern which obliges me to run the app with flutter run --no-sound-null-safety. Is there a way to run unit tests (which requires to run the app with just flutter run) while still running the app with this flag ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that by just lowering the sdk version in my pubspec.yaml